# ball and bins problem can't be model using binomial random variable

Tags: probability

Given 5 balls and 6 bins. We are going to put the ball into the bins randomly, What is the probability that there are n empty after we put the balls into the bins? We let $X$ be the random variable that is the number of empty bins

Here is what I tried:
Let $x_i$ be $1$ if the ith bin is empty after we put the balls into the bins, Then $P(X_i=1)= \frac{5}{6}^5$. And so since the number of emptys is just sum of all $x_i$ be should have $X \sim bin(5,\frac{5}{6}^5)$. But we how come this model doesn't give right solution for $P(X=0)$?

How do you solve this?

Comment: Can a bin have more than one ball?

Comment: yes it could!! right

Comment: Your approach won't work because the prob that bin $i$ remains empty is not independent of the prob that bin $j$ remains empty.

Comment: I think the number of ways for a bin to be empty will be $P(X_i = 1) = \frac{{6\choose 5}*5!}{6^5}$.

Comment: I don't understand how you got that probability?

Comment: @almagest I disagree. how are they dependent?

Comment: @mathpadawan suppose there are 2 bins and 1 ball. is it clear that the event of bin 1 being empty is not independent of the event of bin 2 being empty?